# dplyr filter columns with multiple regex

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have two df in R (meta=some redundant info)

df1:

```
                id  value1  value2  value3  value4
id1_meta_meta-meta  4.93    13.93   16.8    35.39
id2_meta_meta-meta  28.63   45.43   30.52   61.71
id3_meta_meta-meta  3.35    1.26    7.98    4.43
id4_meta_meta-meta  16.78   50.47   32.48   55.52
id5_meta_meta-meta  474.23  807.71  664.45  442.55
id6_meta_meta-meta  26.26   32.83   24.64   41.58
id7_meta_meta-meta  230.1   202.93  166.71  295.48
id8_meta_meta-meta  651.21  1282.71 1012.28 2650.21
```

df2:

```
V1
id1
id2
id3
id4
id5
```

## Question

Trying to filter rows in df1 based on ids in df2

## Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df.common = df1 %>%
  filter(str_detect(id, '*_') %in% df2$V1)
```

## error

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX).
```

## Desired output

df.common:

```
                id  value1  value2  value3  value4
id1_meta_meta-meta  4.93    13.93   16.8    35.39
id2_meta_meta-meta  28.63   45.43   30.52   61.71
id3_meta_meta-meta  3.35    1.26    7.98    4.43
id4_meta_meta-meta  16.78   50.47   32.48   55.52
id5_meta_meta-meta  474.23  807.71  664.45  442.55
```

Comment: Your original code will work if you change the `filter` condition to `filter(str_detect(id, df2$V1))`

Comment: @JakeKaupp I get this error `Warning message:
In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: It's a warning, not an error, and results in your desired output.

Comment: true, rookie mistake apologies but i do not get what I expected `> dim(df.common)
[1]  2 13`

Comment: `str_detect` detects strings and returns TRUE of FALSE, so your code is looking for TRUE or FALSE in `df2`. Instead, use `str_extract` to pull out the ID part and then test with that: `str_extract(id, "id[0-9]+") %in% df2$V1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `gsub` to trim `id` in `df1`

   - `gsub("_.*", "", df1$id)` will remove everything after `_`
2. Check what trimmed `id`'s are in `df2$V2` (this will return row numbers)
3. Extract those rows from `df1`

   ```
   df1[gsub("_.*", "", df1$id) %in% df2$V2, ]
   ```

Comment: It worked, could you comment on whats on going will help to learn, thanks

Comment: Awesome, appreciate it!

Comment: @sbradbio if this is what you wanted you can accept my answer then

Comment: I cannot now, SO will let me accept it after 5 mins, dunno why

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `dplyr` and `stringr`, you can also consider this approach. `str_replace_all` is like `gsub`. `semi_join` is a kind of "filter-join" allowing you to keep records only found match in `df2`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df3 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(id2 = str_replace_all(id, "_.*", "")) %>%
  semi_join(df2, by = c("id2" = "V1")) %>%
  select(-id2)

df3
                  id value1 value2 value3 value4
1 id1_meta_meta-meta   4.93  13.93  16.80  35.39
2 id2_meta_meta-meta  28.63  45.43  30.52  61.71
3 id3_meta_meta-meta   3.35   1.26   7.98   4.43
4 id4_meta_meta-meta  16.78  50.47  32.48  55.52
5 id5_meta_meta-meta 474.23 807.71 664.45 442.55
```

Comment: I will try this, but correct me if I am wrong @PoGibas answer is one liner and concise.

Comment: Well... if you only want to see the most concise answer, I will delete my answer shortly. If you want to learn more about the use of `dplyr` and `stringr` since you are using these packages, I will keep my answer here as an optional approach. What do you say?

Comment: Sure I have accepted it absolutely your are correct it can be optional way.